# Changing HTML5 video src with JQuery causes error only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

I am building a web application using asp.net, Bootstrap and JQuery and currently debugging an issue on LocalHost.

I have a navbar with a dropdown menu containing links to tutorial videos.

When a user selects a video, a modal popup appears containing the tutorial video.

This works perfectly in all browsers, but in Internet Explorer when I select a video, close the modal and then select another video, I receive the following error message:

> "Error Unsupported Video type or invalid file path"

All videos play if they are the first one I select, but if i go to select another i get the above error.

When I inspect the video in developer tools I can see the video source and type are both correct, but when I look at the console it says `AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.`

This only happens in IE and not Chrome/FireFox.

Can anybody point me in the right direction

Thanks

**Drop Down Menu**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Tutorials</li>
    <li><a onclick="ShowTutorial('Tutorial1','/videos/Tutorial1.mp4');">Tutorial1</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="ShowTutorial('Tutorial2','/videos/Tutorial2.mp4');">Tutorial2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery Functions**

```
function ShowTutorial(heading, filepath) {

    $('#modalTutorial').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });

    $('#<%=lblTutorialAlertHeader.ClientID%>').text(heading);

    var player = document.getElementById('tutorialVideo');

    player.pause();

    $('#TutorialSource').attr('src', filepath);

    player.load();
    player.play();

}

function HideTutorial() {

    HideModals();

    var player = document.getElementById('tutorialVideo');

    player.pause();

    $('#TutorialSource').attr('src', '');

    player.load();
}

function HideModals() {
    $('div.modal').modal('hide');
}
```

**Modal Code**

```
<div id="modalTutorial" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h1 class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTutorialAlertHeader" runat="server" Text="Heading"></asp:Label>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalTutorialBody">
                    <video id="tutorialVideo" width="100%" controls>
                        <source id="TutorialSource" src="" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="" onclick="HideTutorial();">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

From your description it is possible this is just an issues with relative vs absolute paths and the base URL for the site.

Historically, Chrome and Firefox have supported relative paths in the site bass tag but IE does not.

See here for some background on links and paths: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html